# Connecting Meteor Application with Exact Online

Tags: meteor

I have made a simple meteor application. I would like to integrate this app with exact online. Does anyone know where I can get some ideas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This website's purpose is to help to solve concrete programming problems. You may first check the help section on how to ask a proper question. It should be your competency to research on exact's API capabilities and design an attempt to connect to it yourself. If you get stuck on a specific level you are very welcome to post a question with a detailed code example, following the guidelines of how to ask a good question.

Comment: Hi George, just echoing Jankapunkt's welcome and comments. Here's where to look in the help section: [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).